# fullcalendar slot label in Persian

Tags: fullcalendar

I have implement fullcalendar, I have interval of 10 minutes, it works fine in English version but Persian version is not displaying interval correctly,
Please view the below screen short, if you see is not showing .30 for second slot, same issue for all slots, is any on know the fix for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to solve my issue, thanks you this post, [FullCalendar SlotDuration 24:00 and weekNumbers: true alters date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915584/fullcalendar-slotduration-2400-and-weeknumbers-true-alters-date-formatting)

```
slotDuration: "00:10:00",
slotLabelFormat: [
'[Week] W',
        'hh:mm'
],
```